# Conditional Copula distribution

Tags: copula

Let C be a Gaussian or Student copula and $F_1, ..., F_d$ empirical margins.

$C(u) = F(F_1^{-1}(u_1), ... F_d^{-1}(u_d))$

I know how to draw from C and get $(u_{1}, ..., u_{d})$
Imagine that I know $u_{1}$. I was wondering how I can draw from C conditional on $u_{1}$. I don't expect a closed form formula as I have no expression for $F_1, ..., F_d$ but how would you 'numerically' generate a serie of conditional draws from $C$?